# Why isn't flow seeing the .random property on my .js.flow file

Tags: flowtype

I'm trying to use a 3rd party library that doesn't have flow types. If I start with `sjcl.random.randomWords(2, 5)` flow tells me it can't find `random`.

sjcl.js.flow:

```
// @flow

declare module sjcl {
    declare type SjclType = {
        random: {
            randomWords: (nwords: number, paranoia: number) => Array<number>,
        }
    }

    declare module.exports: SjclType;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spoke to @asa-ayers on IRC this morning & recording the answer for posterity.

In this example, `sjcl.js.flow` is not a lib file. It is a file that sits next to `sjcl.js`. Flow sees the `.flow` extension, and uses the exported types of `sjcl.js.flow` instead of the exported types of `sjcl.js` whenever someone requires `sjcl`.

Any non-lib file can declare the types that it exports. If it wants to declare CommonJS exports, it can use the syntax `declare module.exports: Type`. If it wants to declare ES6 exports, it can use the syntax `declare export`.

So for example in question, the proper syntax is as follows:

```js
/* @flow */

type SjclType = {
    random: {
        randomWords: (nwords: number, paranoia: number) => Array<number>,
    }
}

declare module.exports: SjclType;
```